# I want to grab the nested tag using XPath in Scrapy

Tags: xpath

Currently, I am solving some problem using Scrapy and XPath, where I am required to grab the nested tag. Assume the condition like this

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
 <td>
  <table>
   <tbody>
    <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
     <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
     <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
  <table>
   <tbody>
    <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
     <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
     <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I only want to grab or select the nested tr (`<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>`). How I should write the XPath for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all `tr` elements that have `td` children but no `table` grandchildren, use the XPath expression `//tr[td][not(td/table)]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
//tr/td[2]/..
```

We select second `td` in `tr` and then just level up to select our `tr` element.